# nofollow drop down select options

Tags: seo

I have a select input on a search results page and each option's value is a URL to sort the search results. There's an onchange event on the select to refresh the page with the sort option. Google webmaster tools is showing that I have duplicate meta content because it's following the sort URL's. Is there a way to put a nofollow on those URL's, or does any one have any ideas on how to mask them from search bots?

Example:

```
<select onchange="javascript:document.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
<option value="/All/All/Category/Length/feet/USD/1/boat_search.aspxltid=0&amp;sort=length_high" >Length: High to Low</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using a [canonical URL](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) to prevent duplicate content?

Comment: +1 How can i not upvote an answer i obviously think is correct?

Answer (score 3):

Don't hide them. Just use [canonical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) on them.